# How rearrange a list in R?

Tags: r

My output is something like this:

```
class(results)
## [1] "list"

results
## [[1]]
##    default   n      FAC2   
## 1 all data 808 0.4740099
## [[2]]
##    default   n  FAC2        
## 1 all data 625 0.968
## [[3]]
##    default   n      FAC2
## 1 all data 796 0.2148241
```

My question here is how to rearrange these outputs in something like this:

```
     n      FAC2
1  808 0.4740099
2  625 0.9680000
3  796 0.2148241
```

Grab all values of n and put them in one `column` and the same for `FAC2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
results <- list(data.frame(default='all data',n=808,FAC2=0.4740099),data.frame(default='all data',n=625,FAC2=0.968),data.frame(default='all data',n=796,FAC2=0.2148241));
do.call(rbind,results)[,c('n','FAC2')];
##     n      FAC2
## 1 808 0.4740099
## 2 625 0.9680000
## 3 796 0.2148241
```

You can forgo the indexing operation `[,c('n','FAC2')]` if you don't mind the `default` column being included in the result as well.

---

Add a column:

```
transform(do.call(rbind,results)[,c('n','FAC2')],new=(n+FAC2)^2);
##     n      FAC2      new
## 1 808 0.4740099 653630.2
## 2 625 0.9680000 391835.9
## 3 796 0.2148241 633958.0
```

Or:

```
x <- do.call(rbind,results)[,c('n','FAC2')];
x$new <- (x$n+x$FAC2)^2;
x;
##     n      FAC2      new
## 1 808 0.4740099 653630.2
## 2 625 0.9680000 391835.9
## 3 796 0.2148241 633958.0
```

---

Column means:

```
rbind(x,apply(x,2,mean));
##     n      FAC2      new
## 1 808 0.4740099 653630.2
## 2 625 0.9680000 391835.9
## 3 796 0.2148241 633958.0
## 4 743 0.5522780 559808.1
```

Or:

```
rbind(x,colMeans(x));
##     n      FAC2      new
## 1 808 0.4740099 653630.2
## 2 625 0.9680000 391835.9
## 3 796 0.2148241 633958.0
## 4 743 0.5522780 559808.1
```

---

Capture list component number in `identity` column:

```
do.call(rbind,Map(cbind,results,identity=1:length(results)));
##    default   n      FAC2 identity
## 1 all data 808 0.4740099        1
## 2 all data 625 0.9680000        2
## 3 all data 796 0.2148241        3
```